# Get 5 highest entries of object array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Yesterday I got my extraction from a csv working but now ran into another wall.
Basically I now have an array of objects with the properties Name, Score and Kills.

I now want to take out 5 objects that have the highest amount of points and sort them from the highest to the lowest of these 5.
For now I only have 4 entries as only 4 individuals connected to the server but I want to already get it to work for the future.

heres my current code :

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('./FFA/csv/rankme.csv')
.pipe(csv({ delimiter: ',', from_line: 2 }))
.on('data', (row) =>
 {
  const keyLookup = ['name', 'score', 'kills'];

const newData = Object.keys(row)
  .filter(key => keyLookup.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = row[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(newData);

  });
```

and this is the output on the console :

```
{ name: 'liHi-', score: '998', kills: '1' }
{ name: 'xyCe', score: '1004', kills: '3' }
{ name: 'Лови Аптечка Брат', score: '1000', kills: '0' }
{ name: 'buronhajredini108', score: '1000', kills: '0' }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: You sort it. Then wth `.slice()` you copy the first 5 elements from the sorted array.

In this example i am taking only 3 out. You can ofcorse change the value. The `0` means it starts from index 0 and slices 3 items out from index 0

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
let data = [];
fs.createReadStream('./FFA/csv/rankme.csv')
.pipe(csv({ delimiter: ',', from_line: 2 }))
.on('data', (row) =>
 {
  const keyLookup = ['name', 'score', 'kills'];

const newData = Object.keys(row)
  .filter(key => keyLookup.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = row[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

data.push(newData);

})
.on("close", () => {
let sorted = data.sort((a,b) => b.score - a.score).slice(0,3)

console.log(sorted);
})
```

Comment: Can I also add this to the code without having to declare data manually ?
So it takes out the info of the csv and immediately sorts it

Comment: @xyCe you need to push your `newData` witch is an object into an array and then filter it

Comment: Thank you so much
I am very new to js and I'm getting lost so easily :b